# Is there any way to manipulate json response in spring boot?

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

My project is about a shopping application build with Spring boot. When I get the shopping cart from the endpoint. It will return JSON like this

```
    {
    "shoppingCartCode": 2,
    "productDetailList": [
        {
            "productDetailCode": 5,
            "price": 21000.0,
            "dateManufacture": "2021-09-23",
            "quantity": 10,
            "colorName": "Pink",
            "warranty": 2,
            "product": {
                "prodCode": 2,
                "prodName": "Z Flod 10",
                "description": "Z Flod  10 Flippable then Break up",
                "brand": {
                    "brandName": "Samsung",
                    "imageList": []
                },
                "shop": {
                    "shopCode": 5,
                    "shopName": "Montri Phone",
                    "shopDescription": "Strict security",
                    "type": "SELLER",
                    "imageList": []
                }
            },
            "imageList": [
                {
                    "imageName": "i-agree.png"
                },
                {
                    "imageName": "i-agree1.png"
                },
                {
                    "imageName": "i-agree2.png"
                },
                {
                    "imageName": "i-agree3.png"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to manipulate the **imageList** to like this

```
"imageList": ["i-agree.png","i-agree1.png","i-agree2.png","i-agree3.png"]
```

Is there any way to manipulate JSON before response? 
or it might need POJO to wrap it up before response again?

Comment: You can use a [Custom Deserializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) for the `imageList` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a custom serializer as follows:

```java
public class ImageListConverter extends StdConverter<List<Image>, List<String>> {
    @Override
    public List<String> convert(List<Image> images) {
        return images.stream().map(User::getImageName).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Now you just need to annotate the `imageList` property:

```java
public class ProductDetail {
    @JsonSerialize(converter = ImageListConverter.class)
    List<Image> imageList;
}
```

The other option would be changing `List<Image>` to `List<String>` and do the conversion when creating `ProductDetail`. It really depends on how you use `ProductDetail` elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! 
It works!

Comment: I have another question if I want to add attribute "amount" in JSON response for counting products in Shoppingcart. Could you give some hints to do that?

Comment: For that one, the easiest approach is to add the attribute itself to `ProductDetail` class. Another approach could be `@JsonAppend` (https://newbedev.com/jackson-how-to-add-custom-property-to-the-json-without-modifying-the-pojo) but it becomes messy.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! i will try